# How can I figure out how the Apple code signing has been done for my Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, codemagic

I am working basically alone on a Flutter project for this company and the iOS Distribution Certificate is about to expire. I know there are different ways to do the code signing. I am trying to figure out which way has been used before for this project.

What I know:
We work with Codemagic but it doesn't seem like we did the signing with Codemagic:

[image]

[image]

Although we created a API-Connect key on appstoreconnect.apple.com with the name Codemagic automation:

[image]

After generating a new iOS Distribution Certificate I tried doing the code signing with the help of Xcode which changed some settings in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:

[image]

The fact that there has been no settings set before my actions I think we did the code singing differently in the past.

My question now is: Are there any files which I could check which would tell me how we did the apple code signing in the past?

Answer (score 0):

1. first you can check artefact types in Codemagic build: if it's `.ipa` your app is signed with Codemagic. If it's `.app` probably somebody else signed it later on local machine
2. let's say you have `.ipa` and using Codemagic for code signing. Check if you have selected correct workflow when you check code signing settings
3. second screenshot you posted is from team settings and works together with `codemagic.yaml` file only. However based on the first screenshot seems you use Workflow Editor (which is default option for Flutter apps), so all settings should be in Workflow Editor, just double check if you reference correct workflow.

hope it will help